# ColorPicker Dialog is not showing in android

Tags: android, android-canvas, color-picker

I have made a very simple drawing app in android ,in that i have used a colorpicker for choose different pencolor i have implemented as below,but on click of "color" button.my app is unfortunately stop(crash)..My code is as below,Please help me for my problem..Thank you in advance..

**Main.java**

```
package com.example.singletouch;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener {
    ImageView pen, color;
    SingleTouchView mDrawView;
    RelativeLayout layout, layout1;
    ImageView remove;
    ImageView eraser;
    private LinearLayout list_color;
    LinearLayout pens;
    private TextView select_color;
    private int selectedColor = 0x00FF0000;
    HorizontalScrollView myplate;
    private Paint mPaint, mBitmapPaint;



    private Path mPath;

    public Canvas mCanvas;
    LinearLayout pen1, pen2, pen3, pen4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDrawView = (SingleTouchView) findViewById(R.id.myview);
        layout1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
        pen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pen);
        pens = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
        pens.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pen1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pen1);
        pen2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pen2);
        pen3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pen3);
        pen4 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pen4);
        eraser = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.eraser);
        remove = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.remove);
        color = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.color);

        pen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                pens.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        });
        pens.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pen1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mDrawView.setPen(SingleTouchView.DrawingPens.PEN_1);
                pens.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });
        pen2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mDrawView.setPen(SingleTouchView.DrawingPens.PEN_2);
                pens.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });
        pen3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pens.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mDrawView.setPen(SingleTouchView.DrawingPens.PEN_3);

            }
        });
        pen4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pens.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mDrawView.setPen(SingleTouchView.DrawingPens.PEN_4);

            }
        });

        remove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                layout.removeView(mDrawView);
                mDrawView = new SingleTouchView(MainActivity.this);
                layout.addView(mDrawView);
            }
        });

        eraser.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mBitmapPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                mPath.reset();
                mDrawView.invalidate();

            }
        });

        color.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // myplate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                new ColorPickerDialog(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this,
                        mPaint.getColor()).show();

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void colorChanged(int color) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



}
```

**ColorPickerDialog.java**

```
package com.example.singletouch;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.graphics.SweepGradient;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class ColorPickerDialog extends Dialog{
    public interface OnColorChangedListener {
        void colorChanged(int color);
    }

    private OnColorChangedListener mListener;
    private int mInitialColor;

    private static class ColorPickerView extends View {
        private Paint mPaint;
        private Paint mCenterPaint;
        private final int[] mColors;
        private OnColorChangedListener mListener;

        ColorPickerView(Context c, OnColorChangedListener l, int color) {
            super(c);
            mListener = l;
            mColors = new int[] {
                0xFFFF0000, 0xFFFF00FF, 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF00FFFF, 0xFF00FF00,
                0xFFFFFF00, 0xFFFF0000
            };
            Shader s = new SweepGradient(0, 0, mColors, null);

            mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            mPaint.setShader(s);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(32);

            mCenterPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            mCenterPaint.setColor(color);
            mCenterPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        }

        private boolean mTrackingCenter;
        private boolean mHighlightCenter;

        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            float r = CENTER_X - mPaint.getStrokeWidth()*0.5f;

            canvas.translate(CENTER_X, CENTER_X);

            canvas.drawOval(new RectF(-r, -r, r, r), mPaint);
            canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, CENTER_RADIUS, mCenterPaint);

            if (mTrackingCenter) {
                int c = mCenterPaint.getColor();
                mCenterPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

                if (mHighlightCenter) {
                    mCenterPaint.setAlpha(0xFF);
                } else {
                    mCenterPaint.setAlpha(0x80);
                }
                canvas.drawCircle(0, 0,
                                  CENTER_RADIUS + mCenterPaint.getStrokeWidth(),
                                  mCenterPaint);

                mCenterPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                mCenterPaint.setColor(c);
            }
        }

        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            setMeasuredDimension(CENTER_X*2, CENTER_Y*2);
        }

        private static final int CENTER_X = 100;
        private static final int CENTER_Y = 100;
        private static final int CENTER_RADIUS = 32;

        private int floatToByte(float x) {
            int n = java.lang.Math.round(x);
            return n;
        }
        private int pinToByte(int n) {
            if (n < 0) {
                n = 0;
            } else if (n > 255) {
                n = 255;
            }
            return n;
        }

        private int ave(int s, int d, float p) {
            return s + java.lang.Math.round(p * (d - s));
        }

        private int interpColor(int colors[], float unit) {
            if (unit <= 0) {
                return colors[0];
            }
            if (unit >= 1) {
                return colors[colors.length - 1];
            }

            float p = unit * (colors.length - 1);
            int i = (int)p;
            p -= i;

            // now p is just the fractional part [0...1) and i is the index
            int c0 = colors[i];
            int c1 = colors[i+1];
            int a = ave(Color.alpha(c0), Color.alpha(c1), p);
            int r = ave(Color.red(c0), Color.red(c1), p);
            int g = ave(Color.green(c0), Color.green(c1), p);
            int b = ave(Color.blue(c0), Color.blue(c1), p);

            return Color.argb(a, r, g, b);
        }

        private int rotateColor(int color, float rad) {
            float deg = rad * 180 / 3.1415927f;
            int r = Color.red(color);
            int g = Color.green(color);
            int b = Color.blue(color);

            ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
            ColorMatrix tmp = new ColorMatrix();

            cm.setRGB2YUV();
            tmp.setRotate(0, deg);
            cm.postConcat(tmp);
            tmp.setYUV2RGB();
            cm.postConcat(tmp);

            final float[] a = cm.getArray();

            int ir = floatToByte(a[0] * r +  a[1] * g +  a[2] * b);
            int ig = floatToByte(a[5] * r +  a[6] * g +  a[7] * b);
            int ib = floatToByte(a[10] * r + a[11] * g + a[12] * b);

            return Color.argb(Color.alpha(color), pinToByte(ir),
                              pinToByte(ig), pinToByte(ib));
        }

        private static final float PI = 3.1415926f;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX() - CENTER_X;
            float y = event.getY() - CENTER_Y;
            boolean inCenter = java.lang.Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y) <= CENTER_RADIUS;

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    mTrackingCenter = inCenter;
                    if (inCenter) {
                        mHighlightCenter = true;
                        invalidate();
                        break;
                    }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (mTrackingCenter) {
                        if (mHighlightCenter != inCenter) {
                            mHighlightCenter = inCenter;
                            invalidate();
                        }
                    } else {
                        float angle = (float)java.lang.Math.atan2(y, x);
                        // need to turn angle [-PI ... PI] into unit [0....1]
                        float unit = angle/(2*PI);
                        if (unit < 0) {
                            unit += 1;
                        }
                        mCenterPaint.setColor(interpColor(mColors, unit));
                        invalidate();
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (mTrackingCenter) {
                        if (inCenter) {
                            mListener.colorChanged(mCenterPaint.getColor());
                        }
                        mTrackingCenter = false;    // so we draw w/o halo
                        invalidate();
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    public ColorPickerDialog(Context context,
                             OnColorChangedListener listener,
                             int initialColor) {
        super(context);

        mListener = listener;
        mInitialColor = initialColor;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        OnColorChangedListener l = new OnColorChangedListener() {
            public void colorChanged(int color) {
                mListener.colorChanged(color);
                dismiss();
            }
        };

        setContentView(new ColorPickerView(getContext(), l, mInitialColor));
        setTitle("Pick a Color");
    }

}
```

**Logcat**

```
08-06 13:16:17.164: E/AndroidRuntime(2421): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 13:16:17.164: E/AndroidRuntime(2421): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-06 13:16:17.164: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at com.example.singletouch.MainActivity$8.onClick(MainActivity.java:184)
08-06 13:16:17.164: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
08-06 13:16:17.164: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14109)
08-06 13:16:17.164: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
08-06 13:16:17.164: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-06 13:16:17.164: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-06 13:16:17.164: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-06 13:16:17.164: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 13:16:17.164: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-06 13:16:17.164: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-06 13:16:17.164: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-06 13:16:17.164: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

...
Please help me..!

Comment: is there any error message?

Comment: post the stack trace its a crash

Comment: @StefanBeike-yep...i am posting my logcat ,..pls check it

Comment: @Raghunandan-i have just posted it check it..Sir

Comment: what is line 184 MainActivity.java? Can you post where you have initialized `mPaint`?

Comment: @Raghunandan-wait i am posting whole Main.java code..

Comment: @Raghunandan-I have posted whole code of main.java..pls check it sir

Comment: @jigar check my post .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not initialized `mPaint` in `MainActivity.java`

```
        new ColorPickerDialog(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this,
                    mPaint.getColor()).show();
```

You have only declared it as a class member but not initalized.

In `onCreate`

```
       mPaint = new Paint();
```

Comment: its working well but pen color is still black...pen color is not changed..:(

Comment: @jigar i doubt you use the same paint object `mPaint` to draw in your view class. That is the reason you don't see the change. Seems you have to use the same paint object to draw also :(

Comment: @RAghunandan-So what should i do sir?can you pls tell me any solution?

Comment: @Raghunandan-Ok i am asking another question.Hope that you will check it...Sir..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18076653/colorpicker-in-android-not-working

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Color Picker](http://chiralcode.com/color-picker-for-android/). Source is available with code samples how to show color picker in dialog.

Comment: I have gone thru it mann ,What i need is how to use it in my app...thats it..!

Comment: Hi Chiral, I would like to use your library.but what if I want to show color picker in rectangle format instead of oval or circle? kindly guide me

Comment: In that case this color picker is not for you. It cannot be displayed as a rectangle. It's based on HSV color model which is cylindrical-coordinate representations of points in an RGB color model.