# ColorPicker in android not working

Tags: android, android-canvas, color-picker

I have made a simple drawing android program for learning ,I have put a colorDialog which is displayed properly bu after selecting any color ,The pen color is not changing ,It still remains "black" the default color.I have tried as below,Please help me for it,My code is as below:

**Main.java**

```
   package com.example.singletouch;

import java.util.AbstractMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;

import com.example.singletouch.SingleTouchView.DrawingPens;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener {
    ImageView pen, color;
    SingleTouchView mDrawView;
    RelativeLayout layout, layout1;
    ImageView remove;
    ImageView eraser;
    Paint mPaint;
    private LinearLayout list_color;
    LinearLayout pens;

    private TextView select_color;
    private int selectedColor = 0x00FF0000;
    HorizontalScrollView myplate;




    private Path mPath;

    public Canvas mCanvas;
    LinearLayout pen1, pen2, pen3, pen4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDrawView = (SingleTouchView) findViewById(R.id.myview);

        layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
        pen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pen);
        pens = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
        pens.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pen1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pen1);
        pen2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pen2);
        pen3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pen3);
        pen4 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pen4);
        eraser = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.eraser);
        remove = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.remove);
        color = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.color);


        pen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                pens.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        });
        pens.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pen1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mDrawView.setPen(SingleTouchView.DrawingPens.PEN_1);
                pens.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });
        pen2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mDrawView.setPen(SingleTouchView.DrawingPens.PEN_2);
                pens.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });
        pen3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pens.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mDrawView.setPen(SingleTouchView.DrawingPens.PEN_3);

            }
        });
        pen4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pens.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mDrawView.setPen(SingleTouchView.DrawingPens.PEN_4);

            }
        });

        remove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                layout.removeView(mDrawView);
                mDrawView = new SingleTouchView(MainActivity.this);
                layout.addView(mDrawView);
            }
        });

        eraser.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });

        color.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // myplate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                new ColorPickerDialog(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this,
                mPaint.getColor()).show();

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void colorChanged(int color) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mPaint.getColor();
    }



}
 class SingleTouchView extends View {
    public static int width;
    public int height;
    public Bitmap mBitmap;
    public Canvas mCanvas;
    public Path mPath;
    public Paint mBitmapPaint;
    Context context;
    public Paint mPaint;
    public Paint circlePaint;
    public Path circlePath;

    public enum DrawingPens {
        PEN_1(6), PEN_2(4), PEN_3(2), PEN_4(1);

        public Paint mPaint;

        private DrawingPens(final int width) {
            mPaint = new Paint();

            mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(width);

            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        }

        Paint getPaint() {
            return mPaint;
        }
    }

    public SingleTouchView(final Context context) {
        super(context);

        init(context);
    }

    public SingleTouchView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        init(context);
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(400, 400, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        // mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);
    }

    public SingleTouchView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs,
            final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        init(context);
    }

    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Map.Entry<Path, DrawingPens>> mPaths = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Map.Entry<Path, DrawingPens>>();

    private Path mCurrentPath;

    private void init(final Context context) {

        setPen(DrawingPens.PEN_3);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        super.onDraw(canvas);

        for (Map.Entry<Path, DrawingPens> entry : mPaths) {
            canvas.drawPath(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().getPaint());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
        float eventX = me.getX();
        float eventY = me.getY();

        switch (me.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mCurrentPath.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            mCurrentPath.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
        }

        invalidate();

        return true;
    }

    public void setPen(final DrawingPens pen) {

        mCurrentPath = new Path();
        mPaths.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<Path, DrawingPens>(
                mCurrentPath, pen));
    }
```

**ColorPickerDialog.java**

```
public class ColorPickerDialog extends Dialog{
    public interface OnColorChangedListener {
        void colorChanged(int color);
    }

    private OnColorChangedListener mListener;
    private int mInitialColor;

    private static class ColorPickerView extends View {
        private Paint mPaint;
        private Paint mCenterPaint;
        private final int[] mColors;
        private OnColorChangedListener mListener;

        ColorPickerView(Context c, OnColorChangedListener l, int color) {
            super(c);
            mListener = l;
            mColors = new int[] {
                0xFFFF0000, 0xFFFF00FF, 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF00FFFF, 0xFF00FF00,
                0xFFFFFF00, 0xFFFF0000
            };
            Shader s = new SweepGradient(0, 0, mColors, null);

            mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            mPaint.setShader(s);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(32);

            mCenterPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            mCenterPaint.setColor(color);
            mCenterPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        }

        private boolean mTrackingCenter;
        private boolean mHighlightCenter;

        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            float r = CENTER_X - mPaint.getStrokeWidth()*0.5f;

            canvas.translate(CENTER_X, CENTER_X);

            canvas.drawOval(new RectF(-r, -r, r, r), mPaint);
            canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, CENTER_RADIUS, mCenterPaint);

            if (mTrackingCenter) {
                int c = mCenterPaint.getColor();
                mCenterPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

                if (mHighlightCenter) {
                    mCenterPaint.setAlpha(0xFF);
                } else {
                    mCenterPaint.setAlpha(0x80);
                }
                canvas.drawCircle(0, 0,
                                  CENTER_RADIUS + mCenterPaint.getStrokeWidth(),
                                  mCenterPaint);

                mCenterPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                mCenterPaint.setColor(c);
            }
        }

        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            setMeasuredDimension(CENTER_X*2, CENTER_Y*2);
        }

        private static final int CENTER_X = 100;
        private static final int CENTER_Y = 100;
        private static final int CENTER_RADIUS = 32;

        private int floatToByte(float x) {
            int n = java.lang.Math.round(x);
            return n;
        }
        private int pinToByte(int n) {
            if (n < 0) {
                n = 0;
            } else if (n > 255) {
                n = 255;
            }
            return n;
        }

        private int ave(int s, int d, float p) {
            return s + java.lang.Math.round(p * (d - s));
        }

        private int interpColor(int colors[], float unit) {
            if (unit <= 0) {
                return colors[0];
            }
            if (unit >= 1) {
                return colors[colors.length - 1];
            }

            float p = unit * (colors.length - 1);
            int i = (int)p;
            p -= i;

            // now p is just the fractional part [0...1) and i is the index
            int c0 = colors[i];
            int c1 = colors[i+1];
            int a = ave(Color.alpha(c0), Color.alpha(c1), p);
            int r = ave(Color.red(c0), Color.red(c1), p);
            int g = ave(Color.green(c0), Color.green(c1), p);
            int b = ave(Color.blue(c0), Color.blue(c1), p);

            return Color.argb(a, r, g, b);
        }

        private int rotateColor(int color, float rad) {
            float deg = rad * 180 / 3.1415927f;
            int r = Color.red(color);
            int g = Color.green(color);
            int b = Color.blue(color);

            ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
            ColorMatrix tmp = new ColorMatrix();

            cm.setRGB2YUV();
            tmp.setRotate(0, deg);
            cm.postConcat(tmp);
            tmp.setYUV2RGB();
            cm.postConcat(tmp);

            final float[] a = cm.getArray();

            int ir = floatToByte(a[0] * r +  a[1] * g +  a[2] * b);
            int ig = floatToByte(a[5] * r +  a[6] * g +  a[7] * b);
            int ib = floatToByte(a[10] * r + a[11] * g + a[12] * b);

            return Color.argb(Color.alpha(color), pinToByte(ir),
                              pinToByte(ig), pinToByte(ib));
        }

        private static final float PI = 3.1415926f;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX() - CENTER_X;
            float y = event.getY() - CENTER_Y;
            boolean inCenter = java.lang.Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y) <= CENTER_RADIUS;

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    mTrackingCenter = inCenter;
                    if (inCenter) {
                        mHighlightCenter = true;
                        invalidate();
                        break;
                    }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (mTrackingCenter) {
                        if (mHighlightCenter != inCenter) {
                            mHighlightCenter = inCenter;
                            invalidate();
                        }
                    } else {
                        float angle = (float)java.lang.Math.atan2(y, x);
                        // need to turn angle [-PI ... PI] into unit [0....1]
                        float unit = angle/(2*PI);
                        if (unit < 0) {
                            unit += 1;
                        }
                        mCenterPaint.setColor(interpColor(mColors, unit));
                        invalidate();
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (mTrackingCenter) {
                        if (inCenter) {
                            mListener.colorChanged(mCenterPaint.getColor());
                        }
                        mTrackingCenter = false;    // so we draw w/o halo
                        invalidate();
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    public ColorPickerDialog(Context context,
                             OnColorChangedListener listener,
                             int initialColor) {
        super(context);

        mListener = listener;
        mInitialColor = initialColor;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        OnColorChangedListener l = new OnColorChangedListener() {
            public void colorChanged(int color) {
                mListener.colorChanged(color);
                dismiss();
            }
        };

        setContentView(new ColorPickerView(getContext(), l, mInitialColor));
        setTitle("Pick a Color");
    }
}
```

Crash log:

```
08-06 15:44:00.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3617): java.lang.NullPointerException
    08-06 15:44:00.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3617):     at com.example.singletouch.MainActivity$8.onClick(MainActivity.java:134)
    08-06 15:44:00.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3617):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
    08-06 15:44:00.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3617):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14109)
    08-06 15:44:00.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3617):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
    08-06 15:44:00.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3617):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    08-06 15:44:00.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3617):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    08-06 15:44:00.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3617):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    08-06 15:44:00.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3617):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    08-06 15:44:00.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3617):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    08-06 15:44:00.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3617):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    08-06 15:44:00.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3617):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    08-06 15:44:00.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3617):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: where do you use the paint object to draw. I mean your drawing view?

Comment: @Raghunandan-its a View.."SingleTOuchView"..i have added its code in my question Sir.!

Comment: You have used mPaint object in view class to draw but you change the color in MainActivity. both are different paint objects. So the draw does not reflect the color change. Make your view class an inner class of your activity class use the same paint object.

Comment: Ohk Sir i am trying this...!

Comment: i can give you my implementation but it will take lot of time modifying yours and finding out what went wrong. i don't have that much time. But if you need i can post my implementation of fingerpaint with color picker

Comment: @Raghunandan-i have posted my logcat ,Its an exception on Click of color.!

Comment: what is Line 134 MainActivity.java?

Comment: @Raghunandan-I have edited my code as per you suggest ,But now it throws an exception..Please tell me Sir.!

Comment: @Raghunandan-its singleTouchView.mPaint.getColor()).show();

Comment: put a break point and start debugging. seems there are many errors which is very difficult to track one change leading to other errors and exceptions . your `mPaint` is null

Comment: @Raghunandan-I have edited my code as you suggested that put your View in main.java.SO pls cheek it,Coz same exception is thrown still..!

Comment: i will post as example use that as a reference i can't help you at each and every step coz its your code.

Comment: use the below add a number picker to increase or decrease stroke with/pen thickness.

Comment: Seems your code is not in sync with the crash log you have posted. i.e line no in crash log doesn't exactly point to any code which possibly could cause NPE. If you can update code of MainActivity.java to the one you used to take crash log, it could show some clue..

Comment: @Please see my code and tell me what should i do to change color of pen pls.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below as a reference. Modify according to your needs. i have used the same color picker that your used.

As you notice the drawing view is a inner class of your activity class and i used a single Paint object so the change in color reflects in the draw.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
        implements ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new MyView(this));

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);

        mEmboss = new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] { 1, 1, 1 },
                                       0.4f, 6, 3.5f);

        mBlur = new BlurMaskFilter(8, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);
    }

    private Paint       mPaint;
    private MaskFilter  mEmboss;
    private MaskFilter  mBlur;

    public void colorChanged(int color) {
        mPaint.setColor(color);
    }

    public class MyView extends View {

        private static final float MINP = 0.25f;
        private static final float MAXP = 0.75f;

        private Bitmap  mBitmap;
        private Canvas  mCanvas;
        private Path    mPath,circlePath;
        private Paint   mBitmapPaint,circlePaint;

        public MyView(Context c) {
            super(c);
            circlePaint = new Paint();
            circlePath = new Path();
            circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            circlePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            circlePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
            circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(4f); 

            mPath = new Path();
            mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawColor(0xFFAAAAAA);

            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

            canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            canvas.drawPath(circlePath, circlePaint);
        }

        private float mX, mY;
        private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

        private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
            mPath.reset();
            mPath.moveTo(x, y);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
        private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
            float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
            float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
            if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;
            }
            circlePath.reset();
            circlePath.addCircle(mX, mY, 30, Path.Direction.CW);
        }
        private void touch_up() {
            mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
            // commit the path to our offscreen
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            // kill this so we don't double draw
            circlePath.reset();
            mPath.reset();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    touch_start(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    touch_move(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    touch_up();
                    invalidate();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    private static final int COLOR_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST;
    private static final int EMBOSS_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;
    private static final int BLUR_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 2;
    private static final int ERASE_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 3;
    private static final int SRCATOP_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 4;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        menu.add(0, COLOR_MENU_ID, 0, "Color").setShortcut('3', 'c');
        menu.add(0, EMBOSS_MENU_ID, 0, "Emboss").setShortcut('4', 's');
        menu.add(0, BLUR_MENU_ID, 0, "Blur").setShortcut('5', 'z');
        menu.add(0, ERASE_MENU_ID, 0, "Erase").setShortcut('5', 'z');
        menu.add(0, SRCATOP_MENU_ID, 0, "SrcATop").setShortcut('5', 'z');

        /****   Is this the mechanism to extend with filter effects?
        Intent intent = new Intent(null, getIntent().getData());
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        menu.addIntentOptions(
                              Menu.ALTERNATIVE, 0,
                              new ComponentName(this, NotesList.class),
                              null, intent, 0, null);
        *****/
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        mPaint.setXfermode(null);
        mPaint.setAlpha(0xFF);

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case COLOR_MENU_ID:
                // color picker
                new ColorPickerDialog(this, this, mPaint.getColor()).show();
                return true;
            case EMBOSS_MENU_ID:
                if (mPaint.getMaskFilter() != mEmboss) {
                    mPaint.setMaskFilter(mEmboss);
                } else {
                    mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);
                }
                return true;
            case BLUR_MENU_ID:
                if (mPaint.getMaskFilter() != mBlur) {
                    mPaint.setMaskFilter(mBlur);
                } else {
                    mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);
                }
                return true;
            case ERASE_MENU_ID:
                mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(
                                                        PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
                return true;
            case SRCATOP_MENU_ID:
                mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(
                                                    PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP));
                mPaint.setAlpha(0x80);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Same color picker you used

```
public class ColorPickerDialog extends Dialog {

    public interface OnColorChangedListener {
        void colorChanged(int color);
    }

    private OnColorChangedListener mListener;
    private int mInitialColor;

    private static class ColorPickerView extends View {
        private Paint mPaint;
        private Paint mCenterPaint;
        private final int[] mColors;
        private OnColorChangedListener mListener;

        ColorPickerView(Context c, OnColorChangedListener l, int color) {
            super(c);
            mListener = l;
            mColors = new int[] {
                0xFFFF0000, 0xFFFF00FF, 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF00FFFF, 0xFF00FF00,
                0xFFFFFF00, 0xFFFF0000
            };
            Shader s = new SweepGradient(0, 0, mColors, null);

            mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            mPaint.setShader(s);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(32);

            mCenterPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            mCenterPaint.setColor(color);
            mCenterPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        }

        private boolean mTrackingCenter;
        private boolean mHighlightCenter;

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            float r = CENTER_X - mPaint.getStrokeWidth()*0.5f;

            canvas.translate(CENTER_X, CENTER_X);

            canvas.drawOval(new RectF(-r, -r, r, r), mPaint);
            canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, CENTER_RADIUS, mCenterPaint);

            if (mTrackingCenter) {
                int c = mCenterPaint.getColor();
                mCenterPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

                if (mHighlightCenter) {
                    mCenterPaint.setAlpha(0xFF);
                } else {
                    mCenterPaint.setAlpha(0x80);
                }
                canvas.drawCircle(0, 0,
                                  CENTER_RADIUS + mCenterPaint.getStrokeWidth(),
                                  mCenterPaint);

                mCenterPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                mCenterPaint.setColor(c);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            setMeasuredDimension(CENTER_X*2, CENTER_Y*2);
        }

        private static final int CENTER_X = 100;
        private static final int CENTER_Y = 100;
        private static final int CENTER_RADIUS = 32;

        private int floatToByte(float x) {
            int n = java.lang.Math.round(x);
            return n;
        }
        private int pinToByte(int n) {
            if (n < 0) {
                n = 0;
            } else if (n > 255) {
                n = 255;
            }
            return n;
        }

        private int ave(int s, int d, float p) {
            return s + java.lang.Math.round(p * (d - s));
        }

        private int interpColor(int colors[], float unit) {
            if (unit <= 0) {
                return colors[0];
            }
            if (unit >= 1) {
                return colors[colors.length - 1];
            }

            float p = unit * (colors.length - 1);
            int i = (int)p;
            p -= i;

            // now p is just the fractional part [0...1) and i is the index
            int c0 = colors[i];
            int c1 = colors[i+1];
            int a = ave(Color.alpha(c0), Color.alpha(c1), p);
            int r = ave(Color.red(c0), Color.red(c1), p);
            int g = ave(Color.green(c0), Color.green(c1), p);
            int b = ave(Color.blue(c0), Color.blue(c1), p);

            return Color.argb(a, r, g, b);
        }

        private int rotateColor(int color, float rad) {
            float deg = rad * 180 / 3.1415927f;
            int r = Color.red(color);
            int g = Color.green(color);
            int b = Color.blue(color);

            ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
            ColorMatrix tmp = new ColorMatrix();

            cm.setRGB2YUV();
            tmp.setRotate(0, deg);
            cm.postConcat(tmp);
            tmp.setYUV2RGB();
            cm.postConcat(tmp);

            final float[] a = cm.getArray();

            int ir = floatToByte(a[0] * r +  a[1] * g +  a[2] * b);
            int ig = floatToByte(a[5] * r +  a[6] * g +  a[7] * b);
            int ib = floatToByte(a[10] * r + a[11] * g + a[12] * b);

            return Color.argb(Color.alpha(color), pinToByte(ir),
                              pinToByte(ig), pinToByte(ib));
        }

        private static final float PI = 3.1415926f;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX() - CENTER_X;
            float y = event.getY() - CENTER_Y;
            boolean inCenter = java.lang.Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y) <= CENTER_RADIUS;

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    mTrackingCenter = inCenter;
                    if (inCenter) {
                        mHighlightCenter = true;
                        invalidate();
                        break;
                    }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (mTrackingCenter) {
                        if (mHighlightCenter != inCenter) {
                            mHighlightCenter = inCenter;
                            invalidate();
                        }
                    } else {
                        float angle = (float)java.lang.Math.atan2(y, x);
                        // need to turn angle [-PI ... PI] into unit [0....1]
                        float unit = angle/(2*PI);
                        if (unit < 0) {
                            unit += 1;
                        }
                        mCenterPaint.setColor(interpColor(mColors, unit));
                        invalidate();
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (mTrackingCenter) {
                        if (inCenter) {
                            mListener.colorChanged(mCenterPaint.getColor());
                        }
                        mTrackingCenter = false;    // so we draw w/o halo
                        invalidate();
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    public ColorPickerDialog(Context context,
                             OnColorChangedListener listener,
                             int initialColor) {
        super(context);

        mListener = listener;
        mInitialColor = initialColor;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        OnColorChangedListener l = new OnColorChangedListener() {
            public void colorChanged(int color) {
                mListener.colorChanged(color);
                dismiss();
            }
        };

        setContentView(new ColorPickerView(getContext(), l, mInitialColor));
        setTitle("Pick a Color");
    }
}
```

Snap Shot. Use the menu button to choose options. This is the same as the fingerpaint api in the samples with few minor modifications.

[image]

Edit:

You can allow users to change pen thickness using a number picker

[how to use number picker with dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944061/how-to-use-number-picker-with-dialog/17944205#17944205)

Comment: its too tuff to understand ,,,can you pls atleast suggest what changes should i do in my code.!

Comment: @jigar this is simpler than your code. you have a custom view which is set to the activity. you choose options using the menu button. To make changes to your code i will have to start studying yours. I suggest you use this as a reference and build upon that. What is the tuff part. If you elaborate may be i can explain so that it becomes easier for you. You need to use the same paint object `mPaint` to draw and to change set the mPaint to the color of user choice.

Comment: @jigar actually pointed out the mistake and suggested an edit but that lead to a different problem. so it is better you start debugging coz its your code.

Comment: @Raghunandan-NOw my pen color is changed but when i am starting drawing by dat color all past drawing changed by that color:            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079847/colorpicker-not-working-properly-in-android

Comment: @jigar and that's why you unaccepted my answer? so why should i answer now?. I will give you a Hint you need to have a new path fro your new draw.

Comment: @Raghunandan-Sir pls dont mind..I just do it so that i can put my problem to you..

Comment: @Raghunandan-I have send you my question link..did you gone thru it ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34907/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-jigar)