# Pick Color for Android

Tags: java, android, color-picker

Is it possible to develop a pick color tool(same as in MS Paint) which gives us the color on which it is pressed. The the tool will work on an image taken from the camera or from the Gallery.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18076653/colorpicker-in-android-not-working. Yes you can build your own color picker or use libraries which help

Comment: and to draw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16650419/draw-in-canvas-by-finger-android